# Tensorflow-serving Doesn't Find Meta Graph Def

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to serve a trained Tensorflow model using tensorflow-serving (loaded on a docker, if that makes any difference)

After training my model, I've saved it using the following code:

```
prediction_signature = (
            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                inputs={'verif': tensor_info_input, 'enroll': tensor_info_input},
                outputs={'similarity_matrix': tensor_info_output},
                method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
    # Restore from checkpoint
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(trained_checkpoint_prefix + '.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix)

    # Export checkpoint to SavedModel
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                         [tf.saved_model.TRAINING, tf.saved_model.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={
                                            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: prediction_signature, 
                                         })
    builder.save()
```

And after running saved_model_cli with the --all flag on the version folder I get this response:

> ```
> MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'train, serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
>
> signature_def['serving_default']:   The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
>     inputs['enroll'] tensor_info:
>         dtype: DT_FLOAT
>         shape: (80, 20, 40)
>         name: Const:0
>     inputs['verif'] tensor_info:
>         dtype: DT_FLOAT
>         shape: (80, 20, 40)
>         name: Const:0   The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
>     outputs['similarity_matrix'] tensor_info:
>         dtype: DT_FLOAT
>         shape: (20, 4)
>         name: add_1:0   Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
> ```

However - when trying to serve, I still get the following error:

> Loading servable: {name: serve version: 0} failed: Not found: Could
>   not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, it seems the problem was I had both tf.saved_model.TRAINING and tf.saved_model.SERVING tags

When I removed the tf.saved_model.TRAINING tag when building the model everything worked